# How to use nested parallelisation in R when the nested loop is contained within a library?

Tags: r, multithreading, r-caret

I'm using the caret library in R and attempting to produce multiple models simultaneously. However, since caret is also capable of parallelization things aren't working properly.

I'm aware that the correct format for nested foreach loops in R is along the lines of:

```
foreach(i=inputarray) %:%
    foreach(j=secondarray) %dopar% { 
        # functions here
    }
```

However, in this situation the closest I can come is something like this:

```
foreach(i=inputarray) %:% {
    trainModel(use="modelName")
}
```

Perhaps unsurprisingly this doesn't work too well, as the outside iterator doesn't get passed in properly and the code doesn't run at all. Using %dopar% instead results in code that works, but each call to trainModel uses only one thread, as visible from task manager when longer models are running.

In terms of system information I'm running Win 10 with R 3.6

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody else finds themselves in need of this, the best solution I found was to create a second thread cluster inside the first `foreach() {}` using `registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(x))` to assign an individual number of threads to each loop. It has the added benefit of allowing you to give each loop a different number of resources for inequal Job sizes too, which is useful for my application. Of course, there's the slight detractor that the outside cluster declaration causes some overhead threads that don't do much and impact performance a little, but overall a decent solution nonetheless.

```
cl <- makeCluster(n)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i=inputarray) %dopar% {
    library(doSNOW)
    registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(x))
    trainModel(...)
}
```